# Disable telnet service on routers?

Tags: linux, services, telnet, adsl-router

I have found that the telnet service is running on a router.
Telnet is publically known to be insecure.

How does one turn off telnet service on adsl routers?
Please advise how one can disable telnet on BT Home Hubs?

Searches done (only 1 listed due to SU reputation):
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=disable+telnet+traffic

Information found (only 1 listed due to SU reputation):
https://forum.backbox.org/security-advisories/netgear-telnet-enable-utility-allows-attackers-to-gain-root-priviledges/

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I disable telnet on BT Home Hubs?

You don't need to.

> Port 23 is blocked on all BT home hubs.

Source [BTCare Community Forums ... Port 23 for telnet](https://community.bt.com/t5/Other-Broadband-Discussions/Port-23-for-telnet/td-p/448433)

Historical note:

Telnet shell access was available in versions (up to 6.2.2.6) on the BT Home Hub 1.0 with appropriate user permissions.

BT subsequently locked down telnet for "security reasons".

Comment: This doesn't answer my question - I realise port 23 may be blocked, but I'm asking how the telnet service itself can be disabled?

Comment: please let me know what your thoughts are on my question in my previous comment. Eg is telnet built into the hardware? If yes which part(s) of a router is this?

Comment: @unseen_rider <shrug> It's part of the OS built into the router.

Comment: Ok thanks. How about other services such as DNS, http, upnp /ssdp - are they typically part of the OS?

Comment: @unseen_rider Of course. Remember that for a router/modem the OS is the firmware (which can be flashed to update on some routers).

Comment: Know any good sites detailing how to alter / amend existing firmware? I would like to make some of my devices more secure by permanently disabling some services.

Comment: @unseen_rider https://www.dd-wrt.com/site/, http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato are the main two.